# Nested subfigures alignment

Tags: floats, subfloats

I'm having trouble creating a 2x2 grid of subfigures. With this tex below, I get a 1x4 grid instead. I'm probably not understanding how the 0.5/textwidth worked, I presumed it used the parent's textwidth?

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
          \centering
          \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
                  \centering
                  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{phone0018-A-crop.jpg}
                  \caption{Left cropped}
          \end{subfigure}
          ~
          \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
                  \centering
                  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{phone0018-A-shift.jpg}
                  \caption{Right shifted}
          \end{subfigure}
    \end{subfigure}
    ~
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
          \centering
          \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
                  \centering
                  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{phone0018-A-stereo.jpg}
                  \caption{Anaglypah of Stereo Pair}
          \end{subfigure}
          ~
          \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
                  \centering
                  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{phone0018-A-diff.jpg}
                  \caption{Difference of Stereo Pair}
          \end{subfigure}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{\texttt{phone0018.pgm} with $D_h = 10$}\label{fig:contrast}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `subfigure` environment from the [`subcaption`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/subcaption) package takes all the same arguments as a `minipage`.

The `minipage` environment adds a small amount of horizontal space at the end of the environment, which you can remove by using a `%` after `\end{minipage}`, or in this case `\end{subfigure}`.

All I've done in the MWE below is replace `~` with `%`; you are correct about your description of `\textwidth`, it uses the parent value.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
          \centering
          \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
                  \centering
                  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{phone0018-A-crop.jpg}
                  \caption{Left cropped}
          \end{subfigure}%
          \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
                  \centering
                  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{phone0018-A-shift.jpg}
                  \caption{Right shifted}
          \end{subfigure}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
          \centering
          \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
                  \centering
                  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{phone0018-A-stereo.jpg}
                  \caption{Anaglypah of Stereo Pair}
          \end{subfigure}%
          \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
                  \centering
                  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{phone0018-A-diff.jpg}
                  \caption{Difference of Stereo Pair}
          \end{subfigure}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{\texttt{phone0018.pgm} with $D_h = 10$}\label{fig:contrast}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```